# Something strange about groupBy on spark

Tags: apache-spark

I'm learning about groupBy function on spark,I create a list with 2 partitions,then use groupBy to get every odd and even numbers.I found if I define

```
val rdd = sc.makeRDD(List(1, 2, 3, 4),2) 
val result = rdd.groupBy(_ % 2 )
```

the result with goes to their own partition. But if I define

```
val result = rdd.groupBy(_ % 2 ==0)
```

the result turns to in one partition.could anybody explain why?

Comment: groupBy(_ % 2 )gets the result 0 or 1 ,and groupby(_ % 2==0)gets the result true or false

Answer (score 0):

It's just the `hashing` applied to `groupBy` Shuffle.

```
 val rdd = sc.makeRDD(List(1, 2, 3, 4), 5)
```

With 5 partitions you see 2 partitions used and 3 empty. Just an algorithm.